# How to concatenate a list of unknown length of data frames with another data frame in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to concatenate a list of data frames with another data frame using pandas concatenate to be used in the training function for Tensor flow. The list contains an unknown number of data frames.

```
import pandas as pd

res_train_x = [a, b, c, d, e....]
# here each variable is a data frame. Ex: a = [], b = [], c = [] and so on
res_train_y  = aa

# this is how I need the code to work
result = pd.concat([a, b, c, d, e, ..., aa], axis=0)

# my existing code
result = pd.concat([res_train_x, res_train_y], axis=0)
```

I am getting this error when I run my existing code.

> TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type ""; only
>   pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid

I need to separate the list `res_train_x` before concatenating with `res_train_y`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message is mentioning, the lists need to be of type `pd.Series` at least for the concatenation to work. To do that, you can simply apply  `pd.Series` on the lists, then you will be able to concatenate. Here is an example

```
import pandas as pd 
# given two lists a and b
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
# if you try to concatenate them with converting to pd.Series
pd.concat([a, b], axis=0)
# You will get a type error:
# TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<type 'list'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid

# if you convert to pd.Series before concatenate, it works:
pd.concat([pd.Series(a), pd.Series(b)], axis=0)
```

The example output is:

```
Out[5]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
0    4
1    5
2    6
dtype: int64
```

---

Overall code to fix your example:

```
import pandas as pd 
res_train_x = [1, 2, 3]
res_train_y = [4, 5, 6]
result = pd.concat([pd.Series(res_train_x), pd.Series(res_train_y)], axis=0)
```

---

Answer to updated question:

if both `res_train_x` and `res_train_y` are lists of dataframe, you need to concatenate the lists and then concatenate the dataframe, like this:

```
all_dfs = res_train_x + res_train_y
result = pd.concat(all_dfs, axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I made some edits to my question. Could you please check it once again? I need to separate ```res_train_x``` before concatenating it.

Comment: @Black_Pulse is aa also a pd.dataframe or pd.Series?

Comment: Both ```res_train_x``` and ```res_train_y``` contain pd.dataframes. I want to know if I can pass the data frames for concatenating them because I have another function to handle the ```result``` if it is either a pd.Series or a pd.dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to concatenate each data frame from the list `res_train_x` to the data frame `aa`.

You could put it in a loop as:

```
for i in range(len(res_train_x)):
    new_df = pd.concat([res_train_x[i], res_train_y],axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks! I have a question, do I only need to pass series or if the data frames as such is enough to use concatenate?

Comment: I tested it only with data frames and it works as expected.